# iOS Old code version stays on phone even after reinstall

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am having a strange issue where even after I uninstall an app that I am developing, the code stays on the phone.

I have an old version of this app on my phone and am fixing some bugs in the code. In Xcode, when I run it on my phone, everything goes well and I get the console output and all but the code version is the previous version, not the current code that is sitting there, in Xcode!

The simulators all run perfectly, always taking the current code and installing that (both in the 5.0 and 6.1 simulators). It only happens on my iPhone 4S.

I have tried everything from adding NSLog() outputs to completely removing the contents of files - the iPhone just doesn't care. Everything says loaded, great, but its not true.

Why in the world is this happening and how the heck can I get it to go away?

Comment: Did you try to clean your build folders? Press & Hold ALT key -> click Xcode menu -> Projects -> Clean Build Folder ... Xcode shouldn't have any 'old' source or compiled code anymore then ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall the app > restart your iPhone >install the new app with a clean build

Comment: Yes, I had to clean it first. Annoying